# BroadcastReceiver how to start new intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I implemented a broadcast receiver to "block" my app if the internet connection is lost.
By block I mean that the app has to open a "No internet connection" activity.

this is my receiver code:

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
    Log.d("** Debug **","noConnectivity " + noConnectivity);

    if(noConnectivity){
        //SHOW NO INTERNET CONNECTION ACTIVITY
    }
}
}
```

Is it possibile to start NoInternetConnection.class when noConnectivity == true??

Thanks!

SOLUTION:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, NoInternetConnection.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just have to call startActivity:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(NoInternetConnection.class));
```

You will need to make sure the "NoInternetConnection" activity is registered in your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".NoInternetConnection"></activity>
```

What issues are you having specifically?

Comment: Thanks, just needed:   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);