# Android SMS Broadcast Receiver checking message format

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

Iam building Android application that checks the format of the received message 
if it starts with $A its starts Activity A and send the content of the message to Activity A 
if it starts with $B it starts Activity B  and send the content of the message to Activity B 
Please Any help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
if(messages.getMessageBody().contains("$A")) {

     //Write your code here

}
else if(messages.getMessageBody().contains("$B")) {

     //Write your code here

}
```

And to pass data to the next activity,do it like this,,

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
```

Then, to retrieve the value try something like:

```
String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
    }
} else {
    newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```

Comment: but smsreciever is a class with no screen its a hidden acticity

Comment: intent i = new Intent ( first screen.this, SecondScreen.class) does not work

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653279/broadcastreceiver-how-to-start-new-intent) and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849868/startactivity-from-broadcastreceiver) too for that..Just call startActivity()